# PHP Как сделать автоматическое скачивание файла с сайта?

Tags: javascript, php, файлы, download

И возможно ли отследить, что файл у клиента начал скачиваться?

Comment: а после скачивания еще и выполняться желательно, да?)

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов нет, если не будет скачивания вывести сообщение и предоставить прямую ссылку html тега с атрибутом download

Answer (score 1):

Никак вы на PHP этот факт не отследите. Дело в том, что не сам PHP передает файл клиенту. Он просто выводит данные, которые сервер должен клиенту передать. А что произойдет дальше, PHP не волнует. Может связь порваться, клиент может отказаться принимать этот файл, да много еще чего. Поскольку PHP не управляет потоком данных, у вас всегда будет только один признак - обратился ли клиент за скачиванием файла или нет.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=test");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
readfile("path/to/file");
```